# Access check in Extbase

Tags: oop, model-view-controller, typo3, extbase

I have a trivial task, but I don't know the expected way to handle it.
I have a controller with:

```
public function getObjectAction($object) {}
```

And I want to ensure, that action will perform only if `$object->getOwner() === $loggedInUser`

Now the question: how this check is supposed to be?

1. Simple if() condition inside of an action, which throws an **Exception** in case of access violation. I don't like this solution, because it will force me to add such an if() in every action, that needs such a check. Sure, I can create some Trait, that performs this check and call `->checkAccess()` from each of such controller actions, but still it looks dirty for me.
2. Controller argument **Validator**. Seems like more reliable solution, because I have separate class, that performs only what it should perform (validate access permissions). But is this really a validation or a misuse?
3. Some heavy system, based on **Signals**, sent before action emitted or so.
4. Your variant (maybe, there is already some ObjectAccessCheck class or so, which I'm not yet aware of).

[Source form TYPO3 lists](http://lists.typo3.org/pipermail/typo3-english/2015-September/094124.html)

Comment: Put all actions into an own frontend plugin and use the normal user restriction from frontend to limit the scope of those actions (you may also make two controller if you want).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution 1 is very simple and you can make it a little bit less dirty.

Assuming you want to perform the check for every action in the controller, you can just use the `initializeAction`:

```
public function initializeAction() {
    if (!$this->myObjectService->isAuthenticatedUserOwnerOfObject($this->arguments['myObject'])) {
        $code = 401;
        $message = 'Authorization Required';
        $this->response->setStatus($code, $message);
        $this->response->shutdown();
    }
}
```

If you have actions in your controller that don't need this check, you might want to split it to two controllers, one for protected and one for non-protected methods.

You can also use the magic initialize*Action for every action, e.g. in your case:

```
public function initializeGetObjectAction()
```

Comment: I like this solution, because it allows to select controllers and/or actions, which shouldn't perform access check and also because access to *Responce* and all other Controller features exists. At the moment, I'm using solution, posted as comment here, but in case I need at least something from your solution benefits, I'll switch to it.

Answer (score 0):

At the end I decided to go for item 3. Current application logic is such, that any controller, which has *MyObject* in arguments should perform access check.

My **ext_localconf.php**

```
$signalSlotDispatcher->connect(
    \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Controller\ActionController::class,
    'beforeCallActionMethod',
    \MyVendor\MyExt\Slot\MyObjectAccessor::class,
    'actionAuthorized'
);
```

**\MyVendor\MyExt\Slot\MyObjectAccessor**

```
class MyObjectAccessor{

    use LoggedInUserAccessor;

    /**
     * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Object\ObjectManagerInterface
     * @inject
     */
    protected $objectManager;

    /**
     * Checks whether current user is allowed to access MyObject, from provided arguments
     * @param string $controller
     * @param string $action
     * @param array $arguments
     * @throws AccessViolationException
     */
    public function actionAuthorized($controller, $action, array $arguments) {
        foreach($arguments as $argument) {
            // if MyObject is accessed and it was persisted before
            if(($argument instanceof MyObject) && $argument->getUid()) {
                $loggedInUser = $this->getLoggedInUser();
                if($argument->getUser() !== $loggedInUser) {
                    throw new AccessViolationException(
                        'Access violation by "' . $loggedInUser->getUsername() . '" with MyObject "' . $argument->getTitle() . '"',
                        1441808407
                    );
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Drawback** of this solution: slot runs for any action, which may eat some resources.

**Benefit**: no controller should know details about access rules for MyObject.